# Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope angular

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I know there are many solutions available to this question and some solutions don't fit angular and some solutions not working. I am following [this blog](https://blog.betapage.co/how-to-add-add-to-homescreen-popup-in-web-app-99d5237fabff) to achieve the `add to Homescreen` feature and I did exactly what is there in that blog and I got the error `Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with the script ('http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').` and then I tried moving the `service-worker.js` to app folder and got the same error. I have created `service-worker.js` in the `src` folder and `script` mentioned in the blog posted in `index.html`. I am working on this for 2 days. any help is very much appreciated. thank you

Comment: Can you please share your angular version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the `service-worker.js` to the assets folder and changed the path `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/assets/service-worker.js')`. it worked !!